# how to create loading screen in libgdx?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I have a `GameScreen` class that renders my game.
but before starting to render the game, it needs to reading files and initializing that is time consuming.

So I need to show/render another `Screen` class called `LoadingScreen` in order to spending some time and concurrently read my files and do initializing process for my `GameScreen`, and after initializing completed changing the screen by calling `setScreen(gameScreen)`.

I need to use thread for making this concurrent work, now the problem is that if I use a thread to read files and initializing; When switching to the `GameScreen` the openGl gives me this error:

```
javax.media.opengl.GLException: Error: no OpenGL buffer object appears to be bound to target 0x8892
at com.sun.opengl.impl.GLBufferSizeTracker.setBufferSize(GLBufferSizeTracker.java:118)
```

I am aware of not both of threads use the graphic resources simultaneously.

I have found that the problem causes with `Mesh`es. Initializing a Mesh in initializer thread and rendering in main thread causes this error. But I don't know how to solve it.

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: What about AssetManager ? http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AssetManager

Comment: Thanks for "AssetManager". It solves some part of problem, but not all. Using thread for initializing still is a problem.

Comment: When using AssetManager you have to call manager.update() till it's finished in your render(). Why can't you there just do some part of the init per render call?

Comment: @Matsemann: I call manager.update() per render call. The problem is after finishing update() calls, I still have some other initialization after reading assets; e.g.: initializing physics engine,... . these works also take some times to do.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, the [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) is the way to load most libGDX resources (audio, textures, etc) asynchronously while showing a splash or loading screen.

For other operations, running them in a background thread (or using one of the other Android or Java background task execution facilities) should be sufficient.  To invoke libGDX routines like `setScreen` or others that need to be executed on the libGDX render thread, use `Gdx.app.postRunnable`, like this:

```
Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         // Do something on the main thread
         myGame.setScreen(postSplashGameScreen);
     }
  });
```

Depending on the visibility of `myGame` and `postSplashGameScreen` it may be easier to construct the Runnable in a different context and then pass it over to the background thread to post when its done.

Comment: This doesn't work me. If I use this approach the new screen goes black. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My workouround is using Actions in my loading screen method:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    stage.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(0.5f), action_loading_assets_and_other_stuff, Actions.delay(0.5f), action_setScreen));
}
```

Actions.delay(0.5f) makes the magic - game not freezing

Answer (score -1):

The action delay did it for me, too. I just sequence a delayaction with 0.2f and a runnable action on the stage in the loading screens show() method. Now the loading screens render method is called a few time while while the 0.2 sec delay which draws the screen and i can proceed stuff in the runnable action.